# Does laravel auth()->attempt() write any session

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I just learn Laravel months ago. There is a small question I'd like to know.
I using auth()->attempt() to do the identity verification successfully. Does Laravel add any session() variable automatic ? If not, do I need to add session variable by myself, or I need to set somewhere.
, thank you very much!
Here is a part of my controller

```
    if (!$check = auth()->attempt([
      'member_username' => request()->$input('username'),
      'password' => request()->$input('pwd'),
      'login_enable' => 1
    ])){
      //processing login successfully

    }
```

Here is a part of web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
// Login successfully route
});
```

Here is a part of auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'account',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'account' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Entity\AccountMain ::class,        
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your guard authentication is `session`, it uses the `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` class. You can see here its `attempt` method:

```php
/**
     * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return bool
     */
    public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false)
    {
        $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember);

        $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

        // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
        // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
        // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
        if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
            $this->login($user, $remember);

            return true;
        }

        // If the authentication attempt fails we will fire an event so that the user
        // may be notified of any suspicious attempts to access their account from
        // an unrecognized user. A developer may listen to this event as needed.
        $this->fireFailedEvent($user, $credentials);

        return false;
    }
```

You can see it calls the `login` method from this guard

```php
/**
     * Log a user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return void
     */
    public function login(AuthenticatableContract $user, $remember = false)
    {
        $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());

        // If the user should be permanently "remembered" by the application we will
        // queue a permanent cookie that contains the encrypted copy of the user
        // identifier. We will then decrypt this later to retrieve the users.
        if ($remember) {
            $this->ensureRememberTokenIsSet($user);

            $this->queueRecallerCookie($user);
        }

        // If we have an event dispatcher instance set we will fire an event so that
        // any listeners will hook into the authentication events and run actions
        // based on the login and logout events fired from the guard instances.
        $this->fireLoginEvent($user, $remember);

        $this->setUser($user);
    }
```

The `updateSession` call is your answer.

Comment: I got it !! ` function updateSession($id) { $this->session->put($this->getName(), $id); $this->session->migrate(true); } ` It put the key of table of MySQL to the session.This really help!

Comment: The session has a strange key field name as **login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d**

Comment: Yes, it ensures the unicity on the session name, whatever the bound entity